# Lock down a Windows PC for kiosk use

Tags: windows

I am writing a desktop application that will run in public areas. The device is running full screen on Windows 7 or 10 and has a touch screen interface. I need to lock down the Windows installation to make it usable and secure - my requirements are:

- No application other than ours can be accessed by a user.
- Windows never displays popups, balloon hints, task bars etc over the top of our application.
- Windows never restarts unless we tell it to.
- ...and, if possible, there should be no indication that this is a Windows OS i.e. no splash screens, no cursor, no task bar while booting etc.

Basically I want Windows to start as anonymously as possible, load our application, then sit back and relax.

I've seen various attempts at kiosk modes, but these are almost always related to Internet Explorer and none of the information I've found online has provided me with what I need.

Comment: Is it a modern application or a desktop application

Comment: It's a desktop application

Comment: Sounds more like a job for Windows embedded.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what Widows Embedded is for. It allows you to trim it down very much, and - in a secure way - select which app becomes the kiosk. https://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products-solutions-overview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you still run an application as the shell in Windows 7/10? I know under XP you were able to replace explorer.exe with the name of your executable, somewhere in the registry I think, and your app would effectively run as the Windows Shell.

(later) - looks like you probably still can;

[Replacing The Explorer Shell](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Admin/ReplacingtheExplorerShellinWindows7.html)

[How To Use And Safely Use Customer User Interface Shell](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-apply-and-safely-use-custom-user-interface-shell-or-explorer-in-windows/)